# Show that $V = \ker T \oplus \operatorname{im}T$ where $T$ is an idempotent linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> I have to prove that if $T$ is an idempotent ($T^2=T$) linear operator then space $V = \ker T\oplus\operatorname{im}T$.

My first try was to think about the basis of subspace $\ker T$.

Let say $(e_1,...,e_k)$ is the basis of $\ker T$ and $\dim V = n < \infty$.

Then, of course we can add $n-k$ vectors to $\ker T$ basis and get the basis of whole space. So every vector $v\in V$ can expressed as linear combination $v = a_1e_1 + \cdots +a_ke_k + a_{k+1}e_{k+1} + \cdots + a_ne_n$.

But then I stuck, because I don't know where to use this idempotency.
Maybe there is another solution which do not consider this basis thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $T^2=T$ so $T^2(v)=T(T(v))=T(v)\Rightarrow T^2(v)-T(v)=0\forall v$ now think a bit what happen if we apply $T$ on  $v-T(v)$

so take any vector $v$ you can decompose it as  $v-T(v)$ and $T(v)$ where $v-T(v)\in Ker(T)$ and $T(v)\in Im(T)$ this is true for all $v$

$v=(v-T(v))+T(v)$

so $V=ker T\oplus  im(T)$

Answer (score 4):

Here's a tricky but quick answer: note that every $v$ can be written in the form
$$
v = (v - Tv) + Tv
$$
and that $v - Tv$ is in the kernel, while $Tv$ is in the image.

To show that the subspaces have a trivial intersection, note that $T(Tv)$ can only be zero if $(Tv)$ was originally zero.  So, no element of the image is also in the kernel. Then, note that $\ker T$ is the image of $I-T$.